# JSON , Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating charts in asp.net C# preparing chart data in JSON string format ,
and sending JSON to Java Script for chart rendering

I prepare the JSON in C# Code behind then sending it to Java Script

Here is my JSON

```
{
   "chart":{

      "theme":"carbon",
      "valueFontColor":"000000",
      "rotateValues":"0"
   },
   "data":[
      {
         "label":"AN INTEGRATED SYSTEMS LLC",
         "value":"859050",
         "link":"newchart-json-AN INTEGRATED SYSTEMS LLC"
      },
      {
         "label":"BAHAN N",
         "value":"623295",
         "link":"newchart-json-BAHAN N"
      }
      
   ],
   "linkeddata":[
      {
         "id":"CO TA L.L.C.",
         "linkedchart":{
            "chart":{
               "captionLinkedChart":"",
               "theme":"carbon"
            },
            "data":[
               {
                  "label":"AN INTEGRATED SYSTEMS LLC",
                  "value":"859050"
               },
               {
                  "label":"Total",
                  "value":"41722065"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is my script that the JSON is called from

```
     <script>
     var json = '<%=jsonString%>';
     
    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
      var satisfactionChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'column2d',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '400',
        height: '300',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: json,
        
      });
</script>




public partial class MYPAGE: System.Web.UI.Page 

{
 public string jsonString = "";
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
jsonString = SendJson(); 
}
```

And SendJson(); will get data from SQL and prepare the JSON format

Comment: In your code, you are trying to pass `var json = '<%=jsonString%>';` as json data source?

Comment: yes , I also tried var json = JSON.parse('<%=jsonString%>'); didnt work also

Comment: Is it valid json format?

Comment: `'<%=jsonString%>'` , is something injected into this string at runtime? Normally you would do a fetch for this type of thing.

Comment: @ThunderboltEngineer yes format is correct as I used validator serval times

Comment: @Krispies 
 public partial class MYPAGE: System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        public string jsonString = "";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                jsonString = SendJson();       
}


And  SendJson();     will get data from SQL and prepare the JSON format

Comment: Can you do a console log to see what the actual value of jsonString is? I'm thinking its just something where you're trying to parse it before it's loaded.